# Calculations with string values from a config file

Tags: bash, shell

I would like to get the time from a config file and the multiply it.
When I write the time like 30m it takes case `m` and uses 30m. But how I can I do calculations with this value.The case `s` is working as it should.

```
 getTimeFromConfig(){
case $timestart in
*s )
echo ${timestart::-1};;
*m )
time = ${timestart::-1}
newtime= $(($time*60));;
*h )
time = ${timestart::-1}
newtime= $(($time*3600));;
esac
}
```

Comment: @123 What do you mean?

Comment: What's the problem/error you face?

Comment: @l3x I don't know how to calculate if I use it with -1

Comment: What's this function supposed to do? Do you get any errors?

Comment: There's no `echo` for the `m` and `h` cases.

Comment: @chroba I added one, it says Row39:1800: command not found  (At least it multiplied, but it doesn't echo)

Answer (score 1):

There shouldn't be any whitespace around `=` (assignment).

```
time = ${timestart::-1}
newtime= $(($time*60));;
```

should be

```
time=${timestart::-1}
newtime=$(($time*60));;
```

Similarly,

```
time = ${timestart::-1}
newtime= $(($zeit*3600));;
```

should be

```
time=${timestart::-1}
newtime=$(($zeit*3600));;
```

---

If you simply want to print the calculated value then do:

```
    echo ${newtime}
```

in each of the case statements of `m` and `h`.

---

If you want this function to "return" the time, you can either use a global variable or print from the function and read it from the caller:

At the end of `getTimeFromConfig()` do:

```
    echo ${newtime}
  }
```

and at the caller:

```
timevalue=$(getTimeFromConfig)
```

Comment: echo ${newtime}, That was my fault.